# Adding image from spreadsheet into an e-mail with Apps Script

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

I'm creating an automatic e-mail which includes many data that change every week.
I'm new in Apps Script and I would like to add an image at the end of the e-mail.

Here the code :

```
// Drive where is stored the image
const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1XXXXXXXXX");

// Retrieve ID file where is stored the image
const file = folder.getFilesByName("file")
const fileIDs = [];

while (file.hasNext()) {
    var files = file.next();
    fileIDs.push(files.getId());
}

var ssFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileIDs[0]);
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ssFile);

//Spreadsheet
var mail = ssFile.getSheetByName("Mail");

//Retrieve image from the spreadsheet
var retrieveImage = mail.getImages()[0];
var arrayImage = new Array();
var image = {};

arrayImage[0] = retrieveImage.getAs('image/png')
image["image"+0] = arrayImage[0];

//Fonction to send mail
function sendEmailS(){
     var message = "Test";
     message += "<img src='cid:image" +0+ "'> <br>";

     GmailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "subject", "", 
                         {
                          htmlBody: message,
                          inlineImages: image
                         }
     );
}
```

I've got the error that **getAs is not a function**. Could help me or give me any clue to finish my script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue and workaround:

From your showing script and the error of `I've got the error that getAs is not a function.`, I thought that the reason for your issue is due to that the image cannot be retrieved as a blob from Spreadsheet.

In the current stage, unfortunately, there is no method for directly retrieving the image on Spreadsheet as a blob. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a workaround. In this workaround, [a Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp) is used. This library supports for the processes that the current Google services cannot directly achieve.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

Please install DocsServiceApp of Google Apps Script library. You can see how to install it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp#how-to-install).

#### 2. Modified script.

When your script is modified using this library, it becomes as follows.

```js
function sendEmailS() {
  // Drive where is stored the image
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1XXXXXXXXX");

  // Retrieve ID file where is stored the image
  const file = folder.getFilesByName("file")
  const fileIDs = [];

  while (file.hasNext()) {
    var files = file.next();
    fileIDs.push(files.getId());
  }

  var ssFile = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileIDs[0]);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ssFile);

  //Spreadsheet
  var mail = ssFile.getSheetByName("Mail");

  //Retrieve image from the spreadsheet
  var retrieveImage = mail.getImages()[0];

  var arrayImage = new Array();
  var image = {};

  const anchor = retrieveImage.getAnchorCell().getA1Notation();
  const res = DocsServiceApp.openBySpreadsheetId(fileIDs[0]).getSheetByName("Mail").getImages();
  const obj = res.find(({ range: { a1Notation } }) => a1Notation == anchor);
  if (!obj) return;
  arrayImage[0] = obj.image.blob;
  image["image" + 0] = arrayImage[0];

  //Fonction to send mail
  var message = "Test";
  message += "<img src='cid:image" + 0 + "'> <br>";

  GmailApp.sendEmail("email@email.com", "subject", "",
    {
      htmlBody: message,
      inlineImages: image
    }
  );
}
```

#### 3. Testing.

When this script is run, an image of `mail.getImages()[0]` is retrieved as a blob. And, an email is sent using the retrieved image blob.

### Reference:

- [DocsServiceApp of Google Apps Script library](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe some ideas here for you?....
...this gets image file from G.drive and emails it...

```
function emailImage(){

fileList = DriveApp.getFilesByName('imageNameInDrive.jpg');
  while (fileList.hasNext()) { image = fileList.next().getId(); }
  var insertImage = DriveApp.getFileById(image).getBlob();  
    
  var message = 'Test<br>';
  message += '<img src="cid:insertImage" > <br>';
    
  GmailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com", "subject", "",
    {
      htmlBody: message,
      inlineImages: {
        insertImage: insertImage
      }
    }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Tanaike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73051890/14271633), which in my opinion would be a good workaround, there is an open Feature Request for converting Spreadsheet images  to BlobSource.

Remember to hit the +1 button to tell Google that you are also interested.

- [Update OverGridImage to support BlobSource interface](https://issuetracker.google.com/119800855)